# how to use json webservice in blackberry cascades

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

1.how to use json web service in blackberry cascades.

2.i need to get data from url link into qml page. give suggession with some sample if possible.

3.my web service link contains array type

for eg: **{ "address":["area": "chn", "city": "ght"]}**

4.description: 
json link --> **192.168.1.251:410/Mobile/Service1.svc/english/Category?CountryID=1**

5.by using above link please tell how to retrive data from json webservice in cascades.. i need answer in cascades method..

Comment: please anybody tell how to retrieve data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right. Well this is really a two part question. First is how to make a request and receive a reply, and second is how to parse the JSON; luckily, Cascades has you covered for both cases.

To make a request:

```
QNetworkAccessManager qNam;
QNetworkRequest req("192.168.1.251:410/Mobile/Service1.svc/english/Category?CountryID=1");
QNetworkReply *reply = qNam.get(req);

connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinished()));
```

Then define the onFinished slot as so:

```
void ClassName::onFinished() {
    QNetworkReply *reply = dynamic_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());

    if (reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt() == 200) {
        JsonDataAccess jda;
        QVariantMap map = jda.loadFromBuffer(reply->readAll()).toMap();

        QVariantList addresses = map["address"].toList();

        foreach(QVariant var, addresses) {
            QVariantMap addressMap = var.toMap();
            qDebug() << "Area is " << addressMap["area"].toString();
            qDebug() << "City is " << addressMap["city"].toString();
        }
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Server returned code " << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt()
    }
}
```

For this to work, this method has to be marked in the class as a `Q_SLOT`.

Comment: Thanks alot dude. Am searching this syntax for 3 days to hit the service for this type. Finally you saved me.

Comment: thanks for your reply. will you tell how to display the received data as list view. data receives as array so it confused slightly.

Answer (score 1):

try this syntax.. if need more get it from here http://qjson.sourceforge.net/usage/

```
QJson::Parser parser;
bool ok;

QVariantMap result = parser.parse (json, &ok).toMap();
if (!ok) {
  qFatal("An error occurred during parsing");
  exit (1);
}

qDebug() << "encoding:" << result["encoding"].toString();
qDebug() << "plugins:";

foreach (QVariant plugin, result["plug-ins"].toList()) {
  qDebug() << "\t-" << plugin.toString();
}

QVariantMap nestedMap = result["indent"].toMap();
qDebug() << "length:" << nestedMap["length"].toInt();
qDebug() << "use_space:" << nestedMap["use_space"].toBool();
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but i expect some sample to understand clearly

Comment: Your solution is good for a non-cascades application. When using Cascades, you already have ``JsonDataAccess``, there's no need for QJSON.